# How to run a sub in a custom "add-in" VBA when an excel file is opened? without having to write custom code in any new file?

Tags: excel, vba, procedure

I'm making an auto-backup for excel and I cannot find a way to run a sub procedure (that starts a timer) in my custom "add-in" code.

I've found the Workbook_Activate or Workbook_Open sub but they must be created in the worksheet and not in the "add-in" therefore everyone who would want to use the backup feature from the add-in should write that code, which is not manageable.

Is there anyway?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry.. after I've asked it I've found this:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
    startBackupTimer
End Sub
```

which works!

Comment: that would be fired when excel opens. Not necessary when the user activates your add-in.

Comment: well, I intent to have the add in working as soon as possible, and with no interaction by the user. The backup-system should be loaded automatically when excel opens up and make backups, real backups, not like the "not existent" excel default auto-save... just this, hope is best practice to attach the add in like this, right? thanks